# How to change active class on a list item

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using reactjs and assume that I have a list of items like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

And I want change the class with styled-components. If a click 'Item 1', I want to give a style to it and if I click the other one, I want to remove active class from 'Item 1' and give it to 'Item 2'

Is it possible with styled-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<ul>
  <li className={`class1 ${this.state.isItem1Active ? "active" : ""}`}>Item 1</li>
  <li className={`class1 ${this.state.isItem2Active ? "active" : ""}`}>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Now the className `class1` will be applied to both the Items and the className `active` will be applied only to the element which is active

Comment: But I can have a 15 of items too. Is there any shortcut without a state like that

Comment: You would be having something like an Id for each item right? So just save that Id in state. Something like `selectedId: null`. Then when item is selected put that id in state. Now you can do something like `className={this.state.selectedId === currentElementId ? "active" : ""}`

Comment: Ok, I will try this solution and mark if it solves my problem. Thanks